# In android dalvik invoke-xxx opcode, what if the argument size is more than 5

Tags: android, dalvik

in the davik vm/mterp/out/InterpC-portable.cpp code, when interpret invokeMethod, I find it can only handle the case when count is less or equal than 5:

```
        switch (count) {
        case 5:
            outs[4] = GET_REGISTER(vsrc1 & 0x0f);
        case 4:
            outs[3] = GET_REGISTER(vdst >> 12);
        case 3:
            outs[2] = GET_REGISTER((vdst & 0x0f00) >> 8);
        case 2:
            outs[1] = GET_REGISTER((vdst & 0x00f0) >> 4);
        case 1:
            outs[0] = GET_REGISTER(vdst & 0x0f);
        default:
            ;
        }
```

then what about the case when the argument size is more than 5?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I miss something, that the senario I mentioned is the case of non-range call, there is a range call that I missed:

```
     */
    if (methodCallRange) {
        // could use memcpy or a "Duff's device"; most functions have
        // so few args it won't matter much
        assert(vsrc1 <= curMethod->outsSize);
        assert(vsrc1 == methodToCall->insSize);
        outs = OUTS_FROM_FP(fp, vsrc1);

        for (i = 0; i < vsrc1; i++)
            outs[i] = GET_REGISTER(vdst+i);

        ....
```

so it's handled here!

Comment: Yup.  See also the Dalvik docs mirror at http://milk.com/kodebase/dalvik-docs-mirror/, in particular "Dalvik bytecode".